# Equivalent Alamofire libraries supporting swift 3.0 and iOS 8.0+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3.0 in my application that have to run in iOS 8.0 and +. While the Alamofire 4.0 doesn't support iOS 8.0, is there any other libraries managing networking like Alamofire but that supports Xcode 8.0, swift 3.0 and iOS 8.0 as a min deployment target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most request the `URLSession` is quite enough and I see no more reason to use any libraries for networking in iOS anymore.

We have a project that started with Alamofire and is ported to Swift 3 so it is still using the same request generation procedure. The call to the Alamofire is then replaced using:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request.urlRequest) { data, response, error in
// Process response
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Everything is on the request, nothing else to do here. The request generation should already be created for the Alamofire so you can reuse the same. Otherwise request.httpMethod = "POST" would be the most primitive way of setting the method.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire 4.0 use stream delegate that are in iOS since 9.0 so you can't use swift 3.0 and alofire 4.0 for iOS 8.0, the only ways are :

- If you wish to use Xcode 8 and Alamofire while targeting iOS 8, please use Alamofire 3.5.0 and Swift 2.3. (Official Answer)
- https://github.com/tonyli508/AlamofireDomain (a custom alamofire to do what you want)

Comment: Can you please tell me what have I to put in the pod file? (pod 'AlamofireDomain', '~> 4.0'? )

Comment: So you should put something like this :
   pod 'AlamofireDomain', :git => "https://github.com/tonyli508/AlamofireDomain"